# Returning a JButtons action listener so another class can use it

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jbutton, actionlistener

I need to listen to a Jbutton getting pressed however the implementation I have doesn't seem correct. In the class that contains the JButton I have

```
public JButton button() {
    return button;
}
```

In the class (call it, `listenerClass`) II listener to the button

```
buttonClass.button().addActionListener(new buttonActionListener());

public class buttonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //local method calls
    }
}
```

I need to have the listener in `listenerClass` because that class contains the logic and methods I require. I feel its not correct to publish the whole JButton. I'm not sure how to just publish the buttons actionListener then I can do what ever I like in `listenerClass`. The `buttonClass` doesn't know anything about the `listenerClass`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See also the [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add custom methods to the `buttonClass` that delegate to the button. For example you could add a method called `addSomethingHappenedListener` that will internally call `button.addActionListener' and the caller does not need to know about the details.

This way the caller does not even need to even know that it's a button just that a certain event happened.